# TypeError: (0 , immer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default) is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I am using this library:
`redux-toolkit`, and, as far as I understand, `immer` library as a part of it. I am trying to start a server and when it renders, I get this error

`TypeError: (0 , immer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default) is not a function`
It then refers to this line in file @reduxjs/toolkit/src/index.ts saying it is not a function:
`enableES5()`.

EnableES5 is imported above like this: `import { enableES5 } from 'immer'`

How do I fix it? I tried changing the index.ts file, but since its a dependency I am not even sure I can change anything there.

Thank you